# Poor performance with Dask

Tags: parallel-processing, benchmarking, dask

Do you think it may be related to the network traffic or shared resources such as the Lustre file system itself or high speed interconnects?

The problem is that in my code, in the function I calculate RMSD there is nothing else being done. It means that it really does not make sense to me why one process should wait this much (about 61s) after it finishes its task. In addition what I expect to see is that all processes have the same time because my task is pleasantly parallel and all processes have the same amount of work to do.
I was thinking that this maybe the scheduler overhead? Do you think Scheduler may cause this overhead?

Also, I am using three nodes with 24 cores each. I set up my network by creating Dask-scheduler in one node and 24 Dask-workers per node. Then during my code, I have a loop over which I change the number of processes (from 1-72) and the measure performance for each N_processes. For example, if I am running my code with 54 processes I have the rest as idle (doing nothing).
Do you think this may cause problem or some overhead?

Thanks in advance,

Mahzad Khoshlessan
Research Associate
Arizona State University
Center for Biological Physics and Department of Physics

---

Hello Mahzad,

I can't tell you why your function ran with varying times. Dask actually has nothing to do with how long these functions take, it just sends your function to a worker, runs it in a thread, lets it run until it finishes, and then keeps things informed about what happened. Perhaps your code has some uncertainty within it? Maybe it depends on some external resource? maybe it just takes a while sometimes? I don't know much about the MDAnalysis project.

However, one useful way to make yourself robust to uncertainty in computations is to submit many more tasks than you have cores. This will allow Dask to load balance appropriately, covering when some tasks take longer than expected.

Also, this mailing list doesn't really seem to be maintained any longer. For Dask questions I personally check github issues and stack overflow. See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/support.html

Best,
-matthew

On Fri, Mar 10, 2017 at 2:27 PM, Mahzad Khoshlessan  wrote:

All,

I am doing some benchmarks and I used a MapReduce parallelization scheme implemented with Dask library to parallelize RMSD fitting function in MDAnalysis library. I was able to get very good speed up when I tried it on a single node using Dask.multiprocessing scheduler but I was not able to get speed up with distributed scheduler across 3 nodes. Here I am going to explain the problem. I measured IO time and compute time for RMSD function in my code. I also measure the total job execution time. Looking at the results calculated using distributed scheduler, I noticed that in some of my tests there is a difference in (compute time + IO time) and total job execution time. When I calculate speed up based on (compute time + IO time) we get very good speed up; while, I get very bad speed up when I calculate it based on total job execution time. In order to see what is the source of this difference I used the Web-interface of Dask to monitor tasks at the low level.

Our task is pleasantly parallel and all processes have the same amount of work to do. Also I am using one thread per process. Here I am showing a test we did on SDSC Comet for 54 processes and 30 processes respectively. The second column shows the number of processes used, third column shows the (compute time+IO time averaged over all processes) measured in our code, the forth column shows the Max (compute time+IO time) measured in our code which shows the slowest process, sixth column shows Max (compute time+IO time) measured using the web interface and the last column is total job execution time.

As you can see in the table (Attached here) there is a difference between the (compute time+IO time) averaged over all processes and the Max (compute time+IO time). My question is that why this is the case because all processes have that same amount of work to do. Also, for the case of 54 processes, web interface shows that one of the processes is much much slower than the others (Max compute time+IO time = 104.25) and based on the measurement in our code (Max compute time+IO time = 43.58). This means that after the process finishes its compute and IO, it is waiting for something else. I am not able to understand why this process is too slow as compared to others. Does anyone with more experience in Dask.distributed has any idea of what might be the reason? Why I am getting poor performance from Dask?
Thanks,